# Look up field from a different Django model given another model field

Tags: python, django

I have two models in Django: `Room` for offices, and `Person` for employees. One office could have multiple employees. I'm trying to make a detail-view html page that shows a person's details, like their name and office number. I can get the details from the `Person` model fine, but I'm having trouble doing a reverse look-up to the `Room` model. How can I get a person's office given the following code?

```
#models.py
class Room(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField('Room number', unique=True)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField('Person', blank=True)
    #...

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Full name', max_length=200)
    #...


#views.py
from django.views import generic
class PersonDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Person


#person_detail.html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>Name: {{ person }}</h1>
    <p>Room: {{ Room.number }}</p>


{% endblock %}
```

All that currently does is return a name, but "Room" is left blank.

Comment: I'm not sure this model design is correct. This way a person can have *many* rooms. Is that what you want?

Comment: You're right, I think probably just one room per person. Should I use a different field type for `Room.persons`?

Comment: See the edit to my answer, a models.ForeignKey is probably what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overload the `get_context_data` method

```
class PersonDetailView(DetailView):
model = Person
context_object_name = 'person'
template_name = 'person_detail.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # woops, typo
    # context['room'] = Room.objects.filter(person=context['object']).first()
    context['room'] = Room.objects.filter(persons=context['object']).first()
    return context
```

And the template:

```
#person_detail.html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>Name: {{ person }}</h1>
    <p>Room: {{ room.number }}</p>


{% endblock content %}
```

Edit:
But you might be better off with `Person` having a `models.ForeignKey` pointing to a `Room`, so a `Person` can only have one `Room`, but many `Person` can have the same `Room`.

You could then keep your orginal view and change your template:

```
    #person_detail.html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>Name: {{ person }}</h1>
    <p>Room: {{ person.room.number }}</p>


{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Adding `office = models.ForeignKey(Room, blank=True)` to the `Person` model and then calling `person.office` in the detail-view worked. Overriding the `get_context_data` method looks cool, but for some reason it just returned an error `Cannot resolve keyword 'person' into field. Choices are: number, persons`. Any idea what that's about? The traceback doesn't refer to any of my files, just system files, and I tried swapping `person` for `persons` in the new code.

Comment: If you didn't do it already, add `context_object_name = 'person'` below `model = Person`. If you do not specify a `context_object_name`, Django creates one for you (I guess `persons` in this case).

Comment: Oh wait, in my overidden `get_context_data` I wrote `Room.objects.filter(person=context['object']).first()`, but `person` should be `persons` (because that is the name of your ManyToMany field). Edit: changed my code, filters works differently for ManyToMany fields.